# Using Vim as a godoc viewer

Tags: vim

Even though the vim-go plugin is suiting me fine, I'd like to know whether there's something better than `godoc io | vim -` for using vim as a temporary documentation viewer in general.

This is not best at first for me because it creates a context of a temporary editable buffer, and I need to `:q!` to exit vim. I use cppman
for checking c++ docs on Vim, it opens Vim automatically and I just need to press q (as usual in manpages) to exit.

Is there a better way for using Vim for this specific workflow?

Comment: Look up vimpager if you really want to use vim as a pager

Comment: Why would you use a text editor as a text viewer?

Comment: @romainl uniform colorscheme & navigation.